# How to choose component values in a current drive circuit for solenoid?

Tags: operational-amplifier, current, analog, solenoid, push-pull

I've designed a current drive circuit for a solenoid using a DAC and a MOSFET push-pull setup with feedback based off Figure 4 and 5 in this application note (https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/an-968.pdf). I need bipolar current control and will be driving +-2A with a 1mA resolution and my circuit currently looks like this:

[image]

I'm confident about the lower half of the circuit being used to change the sensitivity of the differential voltage across the sense resistor. I also understand the diodes being used to bias the MOSFETs in order to minimise crossover distortion and the resistors are there to forward bias the diodes. However, I can't quite figure out the necessity of R8, C1 and R5 - would anyone be able to clarify this for me?
In the application note there is also a positive feedback resistor of 10MOhm at the top op-amp (U1) which I don't see the purpose of, and why would a low resistor value be needed at the output of this opamp? Is that only if you're using a single low-side drive/high-side drive solution to bias the gate?

Additionally, leading on from that, when choosing these resistor/cap values as well as the diodes/MOSFETs, is there anything I should be conscious of with the specs?

When simulating this in LTSpice, the model works fine for DC values, but when I inject a sine wave +/-2A @ 1Hz, I end up with some distortion in the output as well as odd behaviour at intermediate nodes - is this due to the behaviour of the solenoid itself or have I caused this in the circuit somehow? Blue trace is current output, green trace is output of U1.

[image]

Comment: The feedback resistor on U1 appears to be missing.

Comment: Are the +/- 5 V and +/- 24 V rails defined somewhere on your LTSpice schematic that we can't see?

Comment: I see no red trace in the second image.  Did you mean blue?

Comment: @evildemonic yes one of my questions was whether that feedback resistor on U1 was necessary? The rails are also defined elsewhere but you are correct about the trace colour, my mistake I will edit that now!

Comment: The app note shows bjts for the amplifier not mosfets. The mosfets you’ve chosen won’t work well as linear  - they are switching devices.

Comment: You do need the feedback resistor, and as @Kartman mentions you can't just swap in MOSFETs for BJTs.

Comment: @Kartman I'm not sure that's entirely correct? As shown in figure 5 it is possible to use MOSFETs especially in higher current applications, the only difference here is I need a bipolar output hence why I've used a push pull configuration - surely the gate voltage determines your Ids if you're operating in the ohmic region?

Comment: @evildemonic could you please explain the feedback resistor and why you think MOSFETs wouldnt work (see my above comment to @Kartman)

Comment: figure 5 isn't push-pull. figure 4 shows push-pull using bjts. How are the diodes used to bias the mosfets? The diodes work for bjts as bjts are current controlled and the diodes go some way to cancel the diode drop of the B-E junction. Not so with a mosfet. The mosfet gate threshold voltage is usually greater than 0.6V. As well, running the mosfets in their ohmic region means you need to be very careful of not straying out of the safe operating area. Build it and see what happens.

Comment: @sophia_ash The positive feedback is for hysteresis.  U1 is being used like a comparator.  As for MOSFET vs. BJT, I agree with Kartman's assessment.